# How to statically link to libcUrl in Qt on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, curl

I've tried following all the guides I could find online, I'm super close but stuck. The project builds and runs. However it instantly crashes.
I'm using `Qt Creator 3.5.1` with `Qt 5.5.1`, compiler is `MinGW 4.9.2 32 bit`.

The cUrl library I'm downloading from http://curl.haxx.se/download.html is the Win32 Generic `Win32 7zip    7.45.0  binary  SSL     SSH     Viktor Szakáts`

I've added to the .pro file the path to the curl headers `INCLUDEPATH += C:\Lib\C\curl-7.45.0-win32-mingw\include`

Also I've right clicked on the project, clicked "Add library", chose "System Library", selected only Windows and set to link statically, and added both `libcurl.a` and `libcurldll.a`, which are placed in the lib directory of the compiler `C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\lib`. This step added `win32: LIBS += -lcurl` and `win32: LIBS += -lcurldll` to the .pro file.

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    CURLcode result = curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_WIN32);
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();    
    auto retVal = a.exec();
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return retVal;
}
```

What is the reason for the crash?

Note: There are no other uses of cUrl in any of the code (its just a bare application).

Comment: ```libcurldll.a``` links your binary against the shared library (a DLL on WIndows). Use just the ```libcurl.a``` if you want static linkage.

Comment: I'm just curious here, but since Qt provides all necessary classes to perform HTTP requests, why not just use those instead and avoid the trouble altogether ?

Comment: @JanHenke I've removed that from my .pro file and from the compiler's lib folder. Now I get undefined reference errors for the init and cleanup functions.

Comment: @SirDarius Because I have a rather large application already written using cUrl which I'm just trying to wrap in a UI for Windows. I've grown quite comfortable with cUrl.

Comment: Fair point, I do use it pretty often too.

Comment: Sounds like there is more going on than what you have written (probably more than you know too). Are you sure about your liker settings?

Comment: If you use the static library, also make sure that your executable links to the WIN32 network lib, namely ws2_32.lib

Comment: @JanHenke I'm sure you're right. What linker settings are there to change?

Comment: @SirDarius I suppose that will throw an error after I successfully get cUrl working. How can I link to that? Does a version exist somewhere that is compatible with MinGW?

Comment: mingw normally contains "libws2_32.a" which should be used.

Comment: @SirDarius There isnt one with the compiler installed with Qt. However, it seems there may be one that's a part of the QtSDK pack, I'll have to install that and try that also.

Comment: In my Qt installation, it is located at: ./Tools/mingw482_32/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libws2_32.a (relative to the Qt root folder)

Comment: Ah, you're right. Also, I was placing libcurl.a in C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\lib\. I've moved it now to the directory you've mentioned C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\. Still an undefined reference. I'm not sure where to place it (should it matter? I should be able to put an absolute path to it, right? like "win32: LIBS += C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libcurl.a")

Comment: Is it possible to rebuild cUrl from source either into my application or beside it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93720/discussion-between-victor-stone-and-sirdarius).

Answer (score 1):

Download the curl for Windows (64 Bit):

https://curl.haxx.se/windows/dl-7.72.0_5/curl-7.72.0_5-win64-mingw.zip

Or this for 32 Bit:

https://curl.haxx.se/windows/dl-7.72.0_5/curl-7.72.0_5-win32-mingw.zip

first you have to put the folders from curl into the folders from qt.

these are:

"include",
"lib"

into (i use Version 5.14.2 with 64 Bit)

F:/Qt/5.14.2/mingw73_64/lib, F:/Qt/5.14.2/mingw73_64/include

Then go to the .pro File from your Project and add the following line:

```
LIBS += -LF:/Qt/5.14.2/mingw73_64/lib -lcurl
```

notice - you have to take your Path to your lib - directory of your QT Installation.

Now you can test with the following code:

```
...
#include <curl/curl.h>
...

size_t WriteCallback(char *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

...

    CURL* easyhandle = curl_easy_init();
    std::string readBuffer;

    curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com");
    curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);

    curl_easy_perform(easyhandle);

...
```

Here you get the http response from a curl request (example.com).